# *Why* the converse theorem (conjecture) should be true?

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Currently, the following $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ converse theorem due to Cogdell and Piatetski-Shapiro is known: For an admissible irreducible representation $\pi$ of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{A})$, $\pi$ is automorphic if, for all automorphic representation $\sigma$ of $\mathrm{GL}(m, \mathbb{A})$ **with $m\leq n-2$**, the Rankin-Selberg $L$-function $L(s, \pi \times \sigma)$ is *nice* (admits a meromorphic continuation, functional equation, bounded in a vertical strip, ...).
Also, it is conjectured that twisting only with $m\leq n/2$ would be enough.

My question is, *why* one can believe such conjectures? Why half would be enough? I wonder if there's any intuitions or evidences that make us believe the conjecture.

Comment: As I said with one of your recent posts, this would probably be a better fit on MO.

Comment: What is the Rankin-Selberg L-function of a non-automorphic representation? If you ask on MSE then at least try to share what you think you understood about such non-trivial stuff.

Comment: @reuns You can define a rep of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A}_F)$ simply by gluing together reps of $\mathrm{GL}_n(F_v)$, but in general this will not be an automorphic representation. The converse theorem gives you a way of determining whether this rep is automorphic or not.